# Not retrieving last data in database in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to fetch all the SQLite database content and send them via post method. The problem is my code is retrieving all the content except the last content from the sqlite database. Anybody can help me with getting the last content too?

```html
 db=openOrCreateDatabase("StudentDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
   Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student", null);
    if(c.getCount()==0){
     System.out.println("Database empty");
    
     return;
    }
  
    else if(c.moveToFirst()){
     while(!c.isLast()){               //problem in this line maybe
      Sender = c.getString(1);
      TimeStamp = c.getString(2);
      Mesg = c.getString(3); 
      readWebPage(c.getString(0));  //POST method
      c.moveToNext();      
     }     
  
    }
 
    c.close();
 }
```

Comment: while(!c.isAfterLast())?

Comment: @Sevle. I tried that but its not working correctly as its not sending first and fourth content from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use for loop to get data

```
db=openOrCreateDatabase("StudentDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
     Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student", null);
      if(c.getCount()==0){
          System.out.println("Database empty");

          return;
      }

      else if(c.moveToFirst()){
          for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++){             
              Sender = c.getString(1);
              TimeStamp = c.getString(2);
              Mesg = c.getString(3); 
              readWebPage(c.getString(0));  //POST method
              c.moveToNext();                 
          }           

      }

      c.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This looks like the best way which has done the magic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(c!=null && c.moveToFirst())
{
do{
String sender = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("column_name"));
}while(c.moveToNext())

}
```

Comment: Its sending content in random sequence. I entered 6 contents and  it sent 5 contents only. It left out the fourth content.

Comment: Your issue is probably associated with your asynchronous POST i.e. whatever  "readWebPage()" sends, and not with your cursor manipulation. Add a logger before  "readWebPage()" to confirm that.